# rosout logging + topic subscription: not thread safe

Tags: ros, rosout, ros-kinetic, topic, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe I have found a threading issue with ros logging.

If a node subscribes to a topic in one thread and logs to rosout in another, a conflict can occur, since the nodes topic list may be altered while the rosout logging traverses it.

The following error is reported:

> Unable to report rosout: Set changed size during iteration

And what is worse is that tcpros protocol synchronization is lost:

> [ERROR] [1520594758.451498758]
> [/rosout]: a message of over a
> gigabyte was predicted in tcpros. that
> seems highly unlikely, so I'll assume
> protocol synchronization is lost.

> [ERROR] [1520594758.451553409]
> [/rosout]: Exception thrown when
> deserializing message of length [0]
> from [/rosout_test]: Buffer Overrun

> [ERROR] [1520594758.451622886]
> [/rosout]: Exception thrown when
> deserializing message of length [39]
> from [/rosout_test]: Buffer Overrun

Are there any locks or similar in place, so I can safely subscribe/unsubscribe to topics?

This python node reproduces the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from threading import Thread

def topic_callback(msg):
    pass

def my_topic_thread():
    """endless subscribing and unsubscribing to a list of topics"""

    topic_names = ["/some/topic{}".format(i) for i in range(0, 100)]

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        rospy.loginfo("subscribing")
        subs = []
        for topic in topic_names:
            subs.append(rospy.Subscriber(topic, Float64, topic_callback))
            rospy.sleep(0.001)

        rospy.loginfo("unsubscribing")
        for sub in subs:
            sub.unregister()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    rospy.init_node('demo')

    topic_thread = Thread(target=my_topic_thread)
    topic_thread.start()

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        # This logging fails intermittently, because the nodes
        # topic list is changed during logging
        # Error: protocol synchronization is lost
        rospy.loginfo("dummy message")
        rospy.sleep(0.001)

    topic_thread.join()
```

kinetic, ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284911/rosout-logging-+-topic-subscription:-not-thread-safe/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2018-03-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-09**:
This is not an answer, but a recommendation: ROS Answers might not be the best place to report this sort of problem. If you have an MWE and believe it is a bug, it might be more efficient to post to [ros/ros_comm/issues](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues) directly. If you do, please link back.

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-03-09**:
Thanks for the input. Now reported [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1346)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Closing this now the issue is [reported](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1346).

In case you have ideas on how to work around this, I would still like to hear it!

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-09**:
I'm not sure this should be marked as *answered*: until the bug is fixed, or it's clarified that the usage seen in the MWE is incorrect, there seems to be no conclusion.